# Is it true that “What are you drinking?" is used to offer to buy someone a drink?

Tags: spoken-english

I saw this from my dictionary:

> **What are you drinking?**
>
> used to offer to buy someone a drink, especially in a pub ***spoken***.

I am wondering if this usage is indeed applied in practice. *What are you drinking?* to me sounds that they see I'm drinking something and ask what I am drinking at the time. How come it becomes an offer to buy me a drink?

Comment: It's an offer either to buy a drink or to fetch a drink for someone. For instance, if you were at a wedding reception with an "open" bar, you might say it there too, even though you're not buying anything.  It's a friendly indication that you would like the conversation to continue.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo why don't we say *What would you like to drink* instead for this purpose?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo or *what do you want to drink*?

Comment: "Why" is usually unanswerable.  We say what we say.  *What are you drinking?* implies that the speaker is offering *another* round. What have you chosen to drink tonight? I'll get another round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

It's a way of talking to a person without initially using a command or some other request with inherent obligation or further action implied. It takes some pressure off the person being asked, to make a an initial committment.

What **are you** drinking?  vs.  **Let me** buy you a drink.

Similar to this:

**Are you** a good dancer?  vs.  Dance **with me**.

Similar to this:

**Are you** having another drink?  vs.  **We should** have another drink.

This way the asker can assess the interaction and make a nice offer or become disinterested without having made an obligation already. This takes some of the pressure off the person asking the question.

However the goal is typically to buy them a drink, not so much to offer them but to just imply that you will be doing it without the other person's expressed acceptance.

Comment: But is it appropriate to use it when I am actually just sitting there and have nothing to drink? And what/how should I respond to it?

Comment: Yes if you have nothing to drink, you could ask someone near you (who doesn't have a full drink) and it would be implied that you are going to offer to buy their drink. Although it can sound coy. It is generally an indirect way of making an offer.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but I would use "what are you drinking" as a question of someone that I already know, as part of getting a round in rather than introducing myself to  a stranger. But that may be a personal or a cultural (British) thing.

Comment: @BrittKelly I meant someone asks me "what are you drinking?" whilst I have nothing to drink. How/what should I say in this case? It seems to be odd.

Comment: It’s fine to say that. You can ask as a general inquiry, “what are you drinking?” Meaning wow your drink looks good I want one. Or ask as an offer to buy one of what they say they are drinking, “what are you drinking?” I’ll get you another when I order mine. In the US bars can be very busy and everyone is trying to order a drink at the same place at the same time and so it can be a nice gesture to help someone else order a drink with yours. Either question is fine. If the bar is not busy and you just want to buy them something, some people may not understand why you want to buy them something.

Comment: @dan tell them what you’re drinking (I’m drinking whiskey & coke) or what you want to be drinking if you have nothing.

Comment: @BrittKelly what about *what do you want to drink*? Can it be used for the same purpose?

Comment: @dan sure you can. (1) What are you drinking? / (2) What do you want to drink? / (3) Can I buy you a drink? Those are three forms of the same question with three different levels of directness or assertiveness. It’s up to you to decide how assertive you want to be towards the other person. Maybe it’s a business lunch where you SHOULD be buying the person a drink, then be direct and use question (2). Maybe you’re having relatable conversation about a sports team and want to show solidarity, use (1). You see a girl at the bar and you’re not sure if she is there with someone else already, use (3)

Comment: @BrittKelly Thank you very much for your answer and explanations!